# How to use class weights for hot encoded outputs with Keras

Tags: keras

I am new to AI and I am using Keras and Tensorflow to train CNNs. My dataset is heavily unbalanced and I want to use class weights to counter that.

After a small search in the internet I found out that I can use scikit learn's class weight() and sample weight() to get the class weights and sample weights respectively and it can be passed to model.fit() in Keras. But I am unsure how to implement it programmatically for hot encoded outputs.

Can someone provide sample code explaining how to implement classweights for hot encoded outputs with Keras?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at this : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras

Comment: @SaikatKumarDey I saw that post. He gave an example for a single output. In that case the output is either 0 or 1. So i can create a dictionary of class weights. {0:1,1:20 }. But my output is hot-encoded. So how do I implement That?

Comment: Have you looked at other answers? Like this one : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/18722